# Automatically detecting external libraries in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, libraries

I am using Jetbrains PyCharm for Python projects. Is there any way or any extension that can help me to add external libraries by detecting them automatically.
Like if i use
`upper("i am working")` 
PyCharm will detect and ask me to add this library

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import upper
```

Comment: That would be very problematic, because there are certainly going to be many packages with the function `upper`. This is definitely a non-trivial task, and I doubt anyone has tried to address it, especially because people don't tend to use a function if they don't know where to import it from.

Comment: Doesn't `Alt+Enter | Import this name` or `Ctrl+double space`on `upper` work?